Azure Blob Storage Access Issues via Private Endpoint in Azure DevOps Pipeline
I'm facing issues accessing Azure Blob Storage via a private endpoint using a SAS token within an Azure DevOps pipeline. Despite configuring the private endpoint, the SAS token, and the pipeline correctly, I encounter AuthorizationFailure errors when the pipeline tries to perform blob operations like reading and writing. The error message:
azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:70336d7b-201e-005c-179d-938271000000
Time:2024-04-21T03:36:35.5944080Z
ErrorCode:AuthorizationFailure
Content: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthorizationFailure</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation. RequestId:70336d7b-201e-005c-179d-938271000000 Time:2024-04-21T03:36:35.5944080Z</Message></Error>

The code:
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient, generate_account_sas, ResourceTypes, AccountSasPermissions
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO

ACCOUNT_NAME = "****"
CONTAINER_NAME = "****"
account_url = f"https://{ACCOUNT_NAME}.blob.core.windows.net"
account_key = '****'

sas_token = generate_account_sas(
    account_name=ACCOUNT_NAME,
    account_key=account_key,
    resource_types=ResourceTypes(container=True, object=True),
    permission=AccountSasPermissions(read=True, write=True, list=True),
    expiry=datetime.utcnow() + timedelta(hours=1)
)

I think the problem is that my Blob is "Private" and firewall blocked for everyone. I have an private end point, but how to use it into the Azure Pipeline, is it possible?

What kind of Azure Pipelines Agent are you using? if you are using Microsoft hosted agents, then it will not have connectivity by default to the private endpoint as it is a private IP. Try configuring Self hosted agent https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/agents?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbrowser#self-hosted-agents

If you want to utilize the Private Endpoint from your azure pipeline, you will have to create a self-hosted agent that is connected to the same VNET (or a peered vnet) as the Blob Private Endpoint. Microsoft hosted agents simply can not access private endpoints.

I would only add that in my experience implementing self-hosted agents in a VM Scale Set was a lot less daunting than I thought it would be. It does cost the compute cost but if your organization requires private endpoint and cannot accept the exemption that would be needed for Azure Pipelines (and it's no small one) then you just have to eat the cost of compute.

The organization already have a self-hosted computer, could I use this to connect to my private end point?

I can't see where is this configuration, is something that I can add or I need to configurate one from zero?

@LUCASXX If your organization already have a self-hosted agent, and that agent is hosted on the same (or peered VNET) as your private endpoint, you should use that on, unless company policy suggests not to :) Change to the self-hosted agent simply by switching the "pool" attribute in the yaml file, and make sure that you have the right permissions to use it.
